# Как в js сделать split по символу '\'

Tags: javascript, строки, split

Я пытаюсь сделать split строки по символу `\`, не получается, пробовал `\\` тоже самое, просто вся строка возвращается. Кто знает как сделать? Может регулярками как-то?

```js
let a = "ABC\EG\SSDF\NSDFSD\SDFSDF".split("\\");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: ты экранируешь `\\` в одной строке, но не экранируешь в другой - не надо так

Comment: Да, но проблема в том что такова исходная строка, и мне надо разбить её на массив. Как это решить?

Comment: Ты не прав, на самом деле строка у тебя `"ABC\\EG\\SSDF\\NSDFSD\\SDFSDF"`, тогда все разбивается, если ты в самом коде пишешь как в примере `"ABC\EG\SSDF\NSDFSD\SDFSDF"` - это эквивалентно тому, что ты экранируешь символы стоящие после \ и в экранированном виде они являются собой. Поэтому ты не можешь разбить указанную строку по \ так как в ней, на самом деле нет ни одного символа \

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое, я тестировал в консоли, и не учёл этот момент :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var s = document.getElementById("test").textContent;
var a = s.split("\\");
console.log(s);
console.log(a);
```

```html
<span id="test">the\walrus\and\the\carpenter</span>
```

Comment: let a = 'ABC\EG\SSDF\NSDFSD\SDFSDF'.split('\\'); В итоге ABCEGSSDFNSDFSDSDFSDF

Comment: Добавил пример в вопрос.