# как рассплитить данный путь, сложность в том что в начале пути разделители "/", а в конце "\"

Tags: javascript, split

```
'C:/Users/dimaz/Untitled_Folder/mini4/data\2020-12-03\Alexey_Smirnov'.split('/')

['C:',
 'Users',
 'dimaz',
 'Untitled_Folder',
 'mini4',
 'data\x820-12-03\\Alexey_Smirnov']
```

```
'C:/Users/dimaz/Untitled_Folder/mini4/data\2020-12-03\Alexey_Smirnov'.split('\ ')

['C:/Users/dimaz/Untitled_Folder/mini4/data\x820-12-03\\Alexey_Smirnov']
```

Comment: Во входной строке нет никаких разделителей  `\\`(один есть, но случайно), добавьте их

Answer (score 4):

```js
let test = 'C:/Users/dimaz/Untitled_Folder/mini4/data\\2020-12-03\\Alexey_Smirnov';

console.log( test.split(/[\\\/]/g) );

// ["C:", "Users", "dimaz", "Untitled_Folder", "mini4", "data", "2020-12-03", "Alexey_Smirnov"]
```

Comment: А пробовали выполнить это? Оберните в сниппет, запустите и удивитесь ;-) Этот вопрос с 2010 года где-то гуляет не просто так.

Comment: @UModeL а что не так?

Comment: Вот видите, Вам подправили в ответе на двойные слеши? Так заработает, но... В вопросе приходит строка, где слеши все ОДИНОЧНЫЕ!

Comment: @UModeL, строка со слешами **ПРИХОДИТ**, а не литерал в коде, который ТС написал для примера.

Comment: @vp_arth: есть подозрение, что Вы пытаетесь вопрос подогнать под ответ. Подождём автора вопроса.

Comment: По какой горячей клавише добавляется сниппет? А то Ctrl+K добавляет код без сниппета. Целый месяц копирую-втавляю из других вопросов-ответов :-(

Comment: @UModeL: Ctrl+M

Comment: @UModeL спасибо )

Answer (score 2):

Использование в split() нескольких разделителей - не магия, ибо там поддерживаются регулярные выражения.

А вот замена одиночного обратного слеша в строке - давняя проблема. Частично её можно решить использованием [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) :

```js
console.log( String.raw `C:/Users/dimaz/Untitled_Folder/mini4/data\2020-12-03\Alexey_Smirnov`.split(/\/|\\/) );
```

Comment: Вы определили строковый литерал неотличимый от литерала с двойными слешами. В чём разница? В использовании плохо поддерживаемой фичи?

Comment: @vp_arth: Вы лучше при форматировании вопроса за автора, не добавляли бы лишних символов, искажая вводные. Если он ошибся, то поправит сам. Внешний вид - это одно, а суть вопроса - другое.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что в строковом литерале, который вы представили, обратные слэши имеют специальное значение. Чтобы они были в строке, нужно их экранировать, как в ответе @DiD.

Вот пример со строкой из «внешнего» источника(DOM):

```js
const src = document.querySelector('span').innerText;
const dest = src.split(/[\\/]/g);

console.log(src);
console.log(dest);
```

```html
<span>C:/Users/dimaz/Untitled_Folder/mini4/data\2020-12-03\Alexey_Smirnov</span>
```

Comment: Не дублируйте ответы - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1131904/265406

Comment: Где вы его откопали? И с чего взяли, что я его когда-либо видел? Почему отвечаете на вопрос, который является дубликатом известного вам вопроса вместо голоса за его закрытие?