# split() не работает корректно, в начал пути "/" , в а конце "\"

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

```
'C:/Users/dimaz/Untitled_Folder/mini4/data\2020-12-03\Alexey_Smirnov'.split('/')
```

```
['C:',
 'Users',
 'dimaz',
 'Untitled_Folder',
 'mini4',
 'data\x820-12-03\\Alexey_Smirnov']
```

Comment: А как этот вопрос связан с Pandas?

Comment: `split()` работает корректно и делает именно то, что от него ожидается.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1201237/176064

Comment: Проблема та же, во входной строке нет обратных слешей `\202` => `\x82`

Comment: Какова основная цель? А то может и не нужно совсем строку сплитить.

Comment: Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Comment: `bind('path/to\\file'.split('\\'), seg => seg.split('/'))` :) (типичный пример использования монад там, где они не нужны)

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, нужно починить строковый литерал, чтобы исключить специальное значение обратных слешей. В представленной строке некоторые символы испорчены ещё до split().

Можно экранировать служебные символы, либо использовать «сырой» литерал:

```
r'C:/Users/dimaz/Untitled_Folder/mini4/data\2020-12-03\Alexey_Smirnov'
```

Далее, с путями ОС лучше работать не как со строкой, а как с путями ОС.
Например, можно воспользоваться модулем `pathlib`:

```
import pathlib

p = r'C:/Users/dimaz/Untitled_Folder/mini4/data\2020-12-03\Alexey_Smirnov'  
pathlib.PureWindowsPath(p).parts
```

> ```
> ('C:\\', 'Users', 'dimaz', 'Untitled_Folder', 'mini4', 'data', '2020-12-03', 'Alexey_Smirnov')
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
re.split(r'[\\/]', r'C:/Users/dimaz/Untitled_Folder/mini4/data\2020-12-03\Alexey_Smirnov')

['C:',
 'Users',
 'dimaz',
 'Untitled_Folder',
 'mini4',
 'data',
 '2020-12-03',
 'Alexey_Smirnov']
```